# How do I make a form that creates a new related model object that is to be used on that same form?

Tags: python, django, forms, models

Ok, that question I'm sure was confusing. Imagine we have this models:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=MODELOS)

class Contract(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.OneToOneField(Phone)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sign = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need to make a form which can have input for all the fields in those models. In one single page I need to specify the phone's serial and model and the contract's number, notes and sign. The phone field should be the one created in the same moment. How would I manage to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Create two forms and put them in one `<form>` tag in template. Then, process both forms in the same view and link objects manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ilvar suggests, define two [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/)

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone

class ContractForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        exclude = ('phone',)

def add(request):
   ...
   if request.method == 'POST':
       phone_form = PhoneForm(request.POST)
       contract_form = ContractForm(request.POST)
       if phone_form.is_valid() and contract_form.is_valid():
           phone = phone_form.save()
           contract = contract_form.save(commit=False)
           contract.phone = phone
           contract.save()
   ...
```

Also, just curious why you use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`, anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure of this was possible. Only one Phone can have one Contract and only one Contract can have one Phone. That's the relationship.

Comment: Do I need to mark in my model the OneToOne field as null=True and blank=True?

Comment: @marcoamorales it depends on your logic: if contract can have phone field empty then it could be `null=True`. if you allow the field to be leaving blank in Django Admin then it could be `blank=True`.